# How input was taken just using object of Scanner class?

Tags: java, java-7

```
  public class Two {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int c=0;
    while(sc.hasNext())System.out.println(++c+" "+sc.nextLine());

}
}
```

I came across this code and i want to confirm that by taking input directly without using object of any datatype all we are doing is taking input and displaying it and we are not storing it anywhere?

and also how is the condition inside while loop is true for the first time? As we have not given any input yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, your code doesn't store  `sc.nextLine()` , so this value will be discarded past the `System.out.println` instruction.

Also for [hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) :

> This method may block while waiting for input to scan.

so the condition will be met once the stream begins to provide input, and the method will block waiting for this to happen or an `Exception` to happen (e.g : if the Scanner gets closed ).

As long as nothing of those things happen, `hasNext()` method doesn't return, so the condition in `while` is still not evaluated, so the loop is blocked there .

Comment: can you please explain again about how while() loop is working in this code i mean i couldn't understand how hasNext() has blocked while()

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your code:

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)`

The `java.util.Scanner.Scanner(InputStream)` constructor is called, and you have an object `sc` of type `Scanner` which reads from `System.in`.

`int c = 0;`

You now have a primitive `c` of primitive type `int`.

`while(sc.hasNext()) { ... }`

The `while` loop evaluates `sc.hasNext()`, which is `true`. As per the documentation, `sc.hasNext()` returns `true` if and only if the input has another token in it. In your case, this means that the `InputStream` is open.

`{... System.out.println(++c + " " + sc.nextLine()); ...}`

`sc.nextLine()` is the problem. Assuming you have not changed `System.in`, the console/terminal will block the loop (i.e. hold the loop paused) until you give it an input (type in some text and hit `[ENTER]`).

So, overall:

`Scanner::hasNext()` will return true if and only if it is possible to get more input (if you are using `System.in`, this will always be true until you close the scanner).
If you are printing the input directly, you will not be storing any references to it, and no memory will be allocated for it (unless `Scanner.nextLine()` stores it somewhere).

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by ' if and only if the input has another token in it' ?

Comment: So, if the input can be read, it will return `true`, but only if. So, if there is nothing left to read, it will return `false`.